# rightBarButtonItem position change when UIAlertviewController present

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uialertviewcontroller

I am setting the image inside the right bar button item. I have used the default navigationbar.

Anyone is having any idea why it's happening when `UIAlertviewController` present?

Comment: are you used any tags for both

Comment: no I have not set any tag. Right now only one right bar button item there.

Comment: @AshishKakkad no I am not setting nil.

Comment: AlertView just create a window and show it , maybe you can create a custom barButtonItem class and rewrite the function ***drawrect*** to find the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue finally. It's because of I am setting title bar of bar button item to empty string because I have set an image.

Instead of passing empty string just pass `nil` or `single space`.

Don't know what iOS doing behind with titlebar string.

Comment: what is the WTF ?